# Using AmPieChart in amcharts how do you display the total of the grouped section?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Creating a pie chart in am charts using groupPercent = 2.5. The total percentage of this section is displayed but I cannot get the chart to display the total for the section. Any Ideas?

chartSettings:

```
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(context.chartName, chartSettings);
    ChartTitle: "Sales Analysis
    By Customer Code
    Current Fiscal Year
    Last Refreshed: 7/16/2015 10:23 AM"
    angle: 30
    balloonText: "[[title]]: [[View_Total_Sales_formatted]]"
    categoryAxis: Object
    position: ""__proto__: Object
    dataProvider: Array[64]
    depth3D: 20
    export: Object
    groupPercent: 2.5
    groupedTitle: "Other: [[value]] ([[percents]]%)"
    labelText: "[[title]]: [[View_Total_Sales_formatted]] ([[percents]]%)"
    maxAngle: 60
    maxDepth: 30
    minAngle: 0
    minDepth: 1
    outlineAlpha: 0.4
    startDuration: 0
    theme: "light"
    titleField: "view_Customer_Code"
    type: "pie"
    valueField: "View_Total_Sales"
```

Comment: Do you mean to display the sum of the values of the slices that go into grouped chart in the chart label? Also, for the record, when posting to SO, consider posting your code what you have so far as well.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label for the "grouped" slice will use the same `labelText` property. It seems like you are using a metacode `[[View_Total_Sales_formatted]]` to refer to particular field in data to be displayed. Naturally, the grouped slice can't sum up your string-based multiple custom fields.

There are a couple of solutions:

1) Use `[[value]]` instead. It will sum up the values of all grouped titles. The chart can apply number formatting on itself. There are a few properties that allow you to do that:

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#precision
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#thousandsSeparator
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#decimalSeparator

I.e.:

```
labelText: "[[title]]: [[value]] ([[percents]]%)",
precision: 2,
thousandsSeparator: ",",
decimalSeparator: "."
```

2) If the above number formatting options are not enough, you can use [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelFunction) to specify your own JavaScript code to format the labels.

```
labelFunction: function(item) {
  // format value
  var value = Math.round( item.value );

  // format percent
  var percent = Math.round( item.percents );

  // format and return the label content
  return item.title + ": " + value + " (" + percent + "%)";
}
```

Here's a complete setup using the above:

```js
var chartSettings = {
  angle: 30,
  balloonText: "[[title]]: [[View_Total_Sales_formatted]]",
  dataProvider: [ {
    "view_Customer_Code": "Lithuania",
    "View_Total_Sales": 501.9
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "Czech Republic",
    "View_Total_Sales": 301.9
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "Ireland",
    "View_Total_Sales": 201.1
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "Germany",
    "View_Total_Sales": 165.8
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "Australia",
    "View_Total_Sales": 13.1
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "Austria",
    "View_Total_Sales": 12.3
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "UK",
    "View_Total_Sales": 9
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "Belgium",
    "View_Total_Sales": 6
  }, {
    "view_Customer_Code": "The Netherlands",
    "View_Total_Sales": 5
  } ],
  depth3D: 20,
  groupPercent: 2.5,
  groupedTitle: "Other",
  labelFunction: function(item) {
    // format value
    var value = Math.round( item.value );

    // format percent
    var percent = Math.round( item.percents );

    // format and return the label content
    return item.title + ": " + value + " (" + percent + "%)";
  },
  maxAngle: 60,
  maxDepth: 30,
  minAngle: 0,
  minDepth: 1,
  outlineAlpha: 0.4,
  startDuration: 0,
  theme: "light",
  titleField: "view_Customer_Code",
  type: "pie",
  valueField: "View_Total_Sales"
};

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", chartSettings );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: what about it's baloontooltip? to show all the details of OTHER slice there?